# Panel settings do not appear on alt+right-click after installing 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have tried alt+right-click, super+alt+right-click, 1. alt(hold) 2. super(hold) 3. right click and many other "fixes" found in the askubuntu but none of them work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: To clarify, you are using Gnome Panel/fallback? Please [edit] the question to include this.